# python 3.4 base64 binary file

Tags: python

python 2.7 vs 3.4 
I have a file 0xFFFE0D000A (just the beginning of desktop.ini)

```
import base64
file64 = "c:\\test\\out.b64"
base64.encode(open("c:\\test\\test.ini"),open(file64, "w"))
with open (file64) as f:
    b64 =f.read()
print (b64)
```

with 2.7, it outputs //4NAAo= 
on 3.4, I get an error TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface.
tried reading the file as rb and get TypeError: must be str, not bytes.

I have try reading it and encoding it was utf8, but the output the wrong.

any ideas?

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do? You can [convert a string to base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.encodestring) without writing to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python3 are character strings and bytes two different and not compatible types of data. Attention must be paid to use the correct type.

Base64 data encoding and decoding functions process binary data. That's why they accept binary file objects, and not text file objects.

The correct code is:

```
base64.encode(open(infile, 'rb'), open(outfile, 'wb'))
```

and works in both Python2 and 3.